# Can I say that my advisor acted in a bad faith?

Tags: ethics

I submitted ten papers to my advisor based on her assignment within one year, approximately, every two or three weeks, I handed in one paper to the advisor. 
Unfortunately, owing to my negligence, the eighth has plagiarism, the advisor kept silent, two weeks later, I submitted the ninth within the same problem, but advisor still did not contact me. Another two weeks, I emailed my tenth, also the last paper with plagiarism to advisor. 
 After that, my advisor notified me to go to her office where she told me that my last three papers have plagiarism and she already filed a complaint against me to Faculty of Graduate Studies at University...  I was stunned on the spot. 
    Please ask, could my advisor do in academic procedure( without telling the student ahead of time then directly made a report to Faculty of Graduate Studies?

Comment: Rules vary between institutions, and we don't know whether yours allows this; you'll have to consult its regulations.  Certainly it wouldn't be unusual for this to be allowed, or even required.

Comment: Oh, please. Plagiarism is not "negligence". It is a deliberate act of deception. So you, the deceitful cheat, want to know if your _advisor_ acted in bad faith? You're a hypocrite as well as a cheat.

Comment: Even if you didn't commit plagiarism, working in a group where each student pumps out a paper every two weeks is going to be bad for your career. This is a screwed-up situation all around.

Comment: @MadJack I assume this is "paper" in the sense of "essay which will be graded" rather than "article to be submitted for publication".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Ah yes, that would make more sense.

Comment: Did you know that you were plagiarizing in the 8th paper? Or you just come to the realization that you were plagiarizing after she told you?

Answer (score 11):

I am sure you have been told that plagiarism is a punishable offense the moment you enrolled.  He/she is just following university procedure.

Comment: I appreciate prompt comments from keen readers; the scenario I described is I am a Ph.D. student in History. My advisor assigned me to write a series of historiographic papers, but these papers are not marked, that is say, the grade of my qualified candidacy exam is completely based on my written test, no any connection with the previous written papers whereas the last three papers have plagiarism; in such a context, I felt that way my advisor dealt with has malicious motive.

Comment: @peik Seriously, get over yourself. You cheated and you think the person who caught you has a malicious motive? You don't seem to have even the most basic understanding of what you've done.